# Can`t wait for Postgres to be running on dockerized mvn/node/postgres web app (Unknown host error)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using PostgreSQL in my Node.js + Spring web app. To deploy it, I'm using docker-compose and running mvn package inside my backend Dockerfile. However, when I try this, I encounter a connection error to PostgreSQL.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:13.1-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=user
      - POSTGRES_DB=userdb
    hostname: database
    container_name: database
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - './userdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  frontend:
    build: ./user-app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  backend:
    links:
      - "database"
    depends_on:
      - "database"
    build: ./
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/userdb'
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user'
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=user'
```

In my pom.xml file, I define the datasource as follows:

```
<dataSource.url>jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/userdb</dataSource.url>
```

I have come to the conclusion that my backend image does not wait for Postgres to be ready. I tried different approaches to make "mvn clean package" wait for Postgres, but unfortunately, none of them were successful. One of the methods I attempted was using "wait-for-it.sh" script to make my "mvn package" command wait for Postgres, but it did not work as expected. When I run **docker compose up**, the order of execution seems to be sequential, and the backend always runs first, regardless of what I try. As a result, it fails with the error message **"Unknown host database."**

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue? I'm new to Docker and have been struggling with it for several days. My docker compose version is 2.18.1

Comment: Did you try to connect using pgAdmin to the postgres container to verify the container is running ? Did you try using IP address instead of host name and see if that works?

Comment: @Rode093 when i try to use an Ip i get a time out, i tried with localhost and is neither recognised, thats why i started using database as hostname, with no success. Not sure what ip address should i use tho, I'm editing my docker-compose.yml file and pom.xml nd running docker compose up, not sure what other way should i work with